# inline-block SPAN does not allow ENTER for a newline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to use SPAN elemenet which is set with `display: inline-block` so it can contain multiple lines.

When I manually enter text and text reaches EOL, then it will automatically jump to the next line.

But I can't use ENTER to insert newline, because cursors jump outside the whole block.

http://jsfiddle.net/7yLLg2rz/1/

```
<div id="window-kitkat" class="form-control" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="skeleton-block" contenteditable="false">
        <span class="skeleton">
            <span class="skeleton-edit" contenteditable="true">TOPIC HEADING</span>
        </span>
        <span class="skeleton">
            <span>Cx: </span>
            <span class="skeleton-edit" contenteditable="true"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="skeleton">
            <span>Px: </span>
            <span class="skeleton-edit" contenteditable="true"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="skeleton">
            <span>Wx: </span>
            <span class="skeleton-edit" contenteditable="true"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="skeleton">
            <span>Tx: </span>
            <span class="skeleton-edit" contenteditable="true"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="skeleton">
            <span>PEARLS: </span>
            <span class="skeleton-edit" contenteditable="true"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

// Skeleton

.skeleton {
  display: block;
}

.skeleton > span {
  display: inline;
}

.skeleton-edit, .answers-edit {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #C0FFB3;
  display: inline-block !important;
  min-height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing `Shift + Enter` to add a new line to the text without leaving the text box.

An alternative would be using a form.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to artificially create the newline on enter key press:

var spans = document.querySelectorAll('.skeleton-edit');

```
span.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        // prevent default action
        event.preventDefault();

        // append new line
        this.innerHTML += (this.innerHTML.indexOf('<br>') > -1 ? '<br>' : '<br><br>');

        // focus at the end of text
        var range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.setStart(this.childNodes[this.childNodes.length - 1], 0);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
}, false);
```

**DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/7yLLg2rz/3/**